# Draw custom pushpin in code without using an image

Tags: silverlight, bing-maps

I need to draw a pushpin for the Bing Silverlight control that can have the head be a variable color.  I can draw a nice dot like this:

```
    Dim marker As Ellipse = New Ellipse
    marker.Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 11, 255, 0))
    marker.Stroke = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray)
    marker.Width = 10
    marker.Height = 10
```

I'll be making dozens of pushpins, each with a slightly different color for the Fill.  How can I add the pointy part?  I would like to have some amount of flaring out at the top so that it looks more like a pushpin and less like a lollipop.

Examples in C# are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's a reason you need it to be a custom one rather than using the built-in pushpin objects, but if not, you can set the background color on those pushpins like so:

```
myPushpin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
```

As far as actually drawing your own, I'm not as sure.  Could you draw some sort of a triangle?

Comment: Glad it was helpful for you.  I ended up scaling the pushpins up for my application as well as making the font one or two sizes smaller, just so we could fit one more character in the label.